# How does visual studio 2015 add "\Zi" compile option to CUDA Linker? How to remove it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cuda

I use cmake to build C++ project. I didn't add "/Zi" compile option to CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS. But Visual Studio add "/Zi" to CUDA Linker automatically. My library will become pretty big with this option, so how can I remove it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, but what does your CMake file look like?

Comment: @drescherjm, `/Zi` generates `.pdb` which can be used for unwinding stack-traces.

Comment: [\Zi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019) is just a `Debug Information Format`. If you do not need debugging information, you can set `None` in the `Properties->C/C++->General->Debug Information Format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA Visual Studio Integration doesn't make `/Zi` configurable by default.

You can either modify `HostCommandLineTemplate`, `RuntimeApiCommandLineTemplate`, and `CommandLineTemplate` directly in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 10.0.props` or specify an extra `.props` file to customize your build according to [Visual Studio Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019).

Just in case, [Here](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/pull/27477/files) is also an example for customize VS build properties using cmake.